# ASP.NET Core Identity, IdentityServer4 and Changing a password

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I currently am using a combination of ASP.NET Core Identity and IdentityServer4 for my IdP.

If I have a client application that uses my IdP, and I want to give already authenticated users in this client application the ability to change their password, where do I put that change password logic?

Do I redirect the user back to some page in the IdP to allow them to change their password there, then redirect them back to the client app once complete?  Or do I add all of the .NET Core Identity packages into the client app and add the change password functionality there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need access to the IDP database to change the password, so it makes sense to keep the change password logic with IDP, if you have two separate applications.

I would redirect the user back to a page within your IDP application as then you can share that logic between any other client applications that are using your IDP app.

Comment: I did in fact finally get this implemented and did exactly that, as it makes the most sense.